# Mysql insert data into double type

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have problem with mysql, i have query like these

```
SELECT sum(Qty) AS Qty FROM sap_rekap_bc23 
INNER JOIN masterunit_sap ON masterunit_sap.unit = sap_rekap_bc23.Unit WHERE Qty>0 AND invno='T62TJ92013' 
GROUP BY HS_Code,HS_Desc,unit_tpb,Curr,Price,invno
```

And the result show up

```
Qty = 3144.6
```

But when i try insert to another table with my code (on PHP)

```
$qryuraian = "SELECT sum(Qty) AS Qty FROM sap_rekap_bc23
                          INNER JOIN masterunit_sap ON masterunit_sap.unit = sap_rekap_bc23.Unit
                          WHERE Qty>0 AND invno='T62TJ92013' GROUP BY HS_Code,HS_Desc,unit_tpb,Curr,Price,invno";

$listuraian = mysql_query($qryuraian,$conn);
while($item=mysql_fetch_array($listuraian))
                {
                    $inserttmp = "INSERT INTO tmp_sap_rekap_bc23 (Qty) 
                                  VALUES ('".$item['Qty']."')";

                    //mysql_query($inserttmp,$connweb);
                }
```

The Result my `Qty` on `tmp_sap_rekap_bc23`  show `3145`. Why my data instant became rounded?? even tough my table `tmp_sap_rekap_bc23` on `field Qty` was `type Double`??? Any ideas??

Comment: There is an [INSERT ... SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) statement that will avoid needing to use PHP to do the the things MySQL does very well. It also avoid numbers going into PHP and that being cast by implicit rules to an integer you weren't expecting.

Comment: Did you try echo `$inserttmp` before insert ? I have tested a small program like your question but cannot see this error

Comment: @BùiĐứcKhánh Nvm i founded, these is my fault, my type double but the lenght is 255 not 0. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem!!.
Is was my fault. I was set my field `Qty` on `tmp_sap_rekap_bc23` length into 225 not 0. So i changed into 0. And viola is working back normal.

Comment: Violas and violins rejoice